# How to draw text and texture at same time in opengl es android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a problem when I combine layout xml file with GLSurfaceView in opengl ES.
I define text in xml file, and about the texture I'm using opengl to draw it.
But the text's always appear before the texture, and I want to both of them are appeared same time.

Comment: If your GLSurfaceView defined in your XML layout or do you create it and add to the layout with addView()?

Comment: hi samgak, my GLSurefaceView is defined in my xml layout file.

Comment: Is your text before or after your GLSurfaceView in the XML?

Comment: I defined GLSurfaceView before text in XML!